# Export / copy Access Pivot Table View to Excel 2003?

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel-2003

Is there a way to copy an Access 2003 pivot table view (used to pivot 206,000 records) to Excel 2003 using VBA?

Comment: The number of records means you can't export to Excel 2003 unless you partition the data set into individual worksheets that have fewer rows than the Excel 2003 limits. Do you not have Excel 2007/2010 available?

Comment: We've had Office 2007 for years, and Office 2010 for a month or two -- but just not the business power users. IT governance issue.

Comment: Our power users have both 2003 & 2007 installed to handle the larger datasets, and allow them to convert 2003 code at their own pace. There are issues, but we've managed to work around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if number of records matters unless the result exceeds Excel 2003 column and/or row max.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel11, "qryPivot_Table_Name", "C:\Users\user\Documents\PivotTable.xlsx", True
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing that exports the actual table (or query) not the pivot), which runs up against Excel 2003's 65,536 row limit. So, I would just like to export the pivot table view, i.e., just the results.

Comment: The query is a pivot type, what else would it export besides the result set of the pivot table query?

Comment: My result set for this pivot is over 200,000 records. I'd like to export the "pivot table view" (with hidden details) -- a summary that is only 40 rows.

Comment: If you write a query that returns 40 rows, that's all that gets exported. You're not going to get around the row limit.

Comment: acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12 will work only in A2007 and A2010, and will create a spreadsheet that Excel 2003 can't open, no?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - Good catch. Use Excel11 for 2003. There are ways for 2003 to open a 2007 file (2007 Microsoft Office system Compatibility Pack for Excel), but not needed when you can control the version.

Comment: FYI, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9 is as high as it goes in 2003... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPivot_Table_Name", acViewPivotTable
DoCmd.RunCommand AcCommand.acCmdPivotTableExportToExcel`

after that you just need to get a reference to the new workboook through Excel.Application object

Comment: Thanks, but although this exports the pivot, it also exports the data table behind it -- which counters the purpose of the question -- to find a "lightweight" method to export only the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a visible display of the data, such as the totals, Ctrl+C the selected range you want to show, then Shift+Edit+Paste Picture Link. When data is updated it will change the image. I would think you can adapt this to a macro, and generate what you want to distribute, fairly easily.

Comment: Well, we've upgraded to Office 2010. How does one copy an Access pivot table as an linked image? I've only been able to copy the pivot table as text. As far as I can tell, the method you describe does not work in Access, though it may work for Excel, Word, etc.

Comment: sorry, I misread and thought you were pulling into excel first and then wanted to display the pivot from there and not send the whole data load around. Once you pull a query into excel it is a possibility. You might reproduce a query that would allow that from excel

Comment: You can save a query for you pivot table in access. Then generate a table from that pivot table query and pull into excel with a filtering query that limits the display. You may be able to significantly limit what is imported to your sheet and then present a merely pasted link of the relevant final display in your reporting.